# Python Pandas manipulation, recursive multiple criteria operations

Tags: python, pandas, finance

I've got a dataset with three different variables (year, ticker and attributes) and their corresponding values (see example below).

I have multiple operations/calculations to apply by selecting certains `attributes` and making sure they're applied to their respective `year`and `ticker`(ex: AAC's `WORKINGCAPITAL` for 2015 divided by AAC's `ASSETSC` for 2015), and will need to store the data for every one of those calculations. Don't mind the date format by the way, I have already taken care of it.

```
    date        value        ticker attributes
0   2013-12-31  0.000000e+00    AAC ACCOCI
1   2014-12-31  0.000000e+00    AAC ACCOCI
2   2015-12-31  0.000000e+00    AAC ACCOCI
3   2013-12-31  2.952900e+07    AAC ASSETSC
4   2014-12-31  7.992200e+07    AAC ASSETSC
5   2015-12-31  8.652400e+07    AAC ASSETSC
... ... ... ... ...
839968  2009-12-31  1.643200e+07    Z   WORKINGCAPITAL
839969  2010-12-31  1.194100e+07    Z   WORKINGCAPITAL
839970  2011-12-31  7.171300e+07    Z   WORKINGCAPITAL
839971  2012-12-31  1.846610e+08    Z   WORKINGCAPITAL
839972  2013-12-31  2.829030e+08    Z   WORKINGCAPITAL
839973  2014-12-31  3.521410e+08    Z   WORKINGCAPITAL
839974  2015-12-31  4.936720e+08    Z   WORKINGCAPITAL
```

I've came up with two alternatives :

1. Pivot the table on attributes and do the operations by column index (ex: `results['WrkCapPct'] = df['WORKINGCAPITAL']/df['ASSETSC']`).
2. Use a recursive operation and making sure it matches `year` and `ticker`.

> Alternative 1 is the simplest for me (at least if I were in R), and
>   I've managed to produce a `pivot_table` which mostly does the trick.
>
> ```
> pd.pivot_table(df, values='value', index=['ticker', 'year'],columns='attributes')
> ```
>
> But from that point on, I must admit I'm stuck for the calculations
>   and data storage in a new data frame column.

I've managed to do it in R, but I want to get operational with Python, as I only have one life and no server farm.

> For alternative 2, I have tried a few things, but I have no clue how
>   to do this other than brute force it. I would resort to it only if it
>   is most computationally efficient, which I highly doubt.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: So alternative 1 should be the approach and you've experienced it works, but you're unclear about where you're stuck there. It seems you know how to do the calculation by dividing two columns, so what's is the real issue there? Please update your question to give more details.

Comment: To be honest, I hadn't even tried it as I was convinced it wouldn't work. I thought (as in Excel) you had to pass your function in the `pivot_table` function and that it couldn't "store" the data. I'm just getting used to differences between R data frames and pandas.

Comment: No because here you simply want to rearrange your long column of items into columns. Give it a try and you will see it works as you would expect. You may even want to use `pivot` that has lighter parameters and should match what you're looking for.